# Create an int[] from Dictionary<int, List<int>>, from each dictionary element's Value List<int> I need an array which contains all dictionary elements

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

The solution I have for now is as...

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> oDict = <Some code to fill in the dictionary>;  

var oList = new List<int>();  
oDict.Values.ForEach(oList.AddRange);   
oList.ToArray();
```

Is there a way to do this without using the additional `List<int>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, that looks like:

```
var array = oDict.Values.SelectMany(list => list).ToArray();
```

(If you only want distinct elements, just call `Distinct` before `ToArray`.)